# Better egonomics for TypeScript union-narrowing typeguard function

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-generics, discriminated-union

We have a utility in our codebase to generate a typeguard to narrow a discriminated union:

```
export type ExtractBranchFromUnion<
  UNION,
  DISCRIMINANT extends keyof UNION,
  BRANCH extends UNION[DISCRIMINANT],
> = UNION extends Record<DISCRIMINANT, BRANCH> ? UNION : never;

export function narrow<
  UNION,
  DISCRIMINANT extends keyof UNION,
  BRANCH extends UNION[DISCRIMINANT],
>(
  discriminate: DISCRIMINANT,
  branch: BRANCH,
): (
  item: UNION,
) => item is ExtractBranchFromUnion<UNION, DISCRIMINANT, BRANCH> {
  return (item): item is ExtractBranchFromUnion<UNION, DISCRIMINANT, BRANCH> =>
    item[discriminate] === branch;
}
```

It can be used easily in a `filter` call to narrow an array down to a specific union member, however it requires that you remember to add `as const` after a string literal `branch` argument, otherwise it infers the type incorrectly and gives you too wide of a result:

```
type A = {type: 'A'; a: string};
type B = {type: 'B'; b: string};
type SimpleUnion = A | B;
const arr: SimpleUnion[] = [];

// BAD: type is SimpleUnion[]
const badListOfBs = arr.filter(narrow('type', 'B'));

// GOOD: type is B[]
const goodListOfBs = arr.filter(narrow('type', 'B' as const));
```

While this issue can be partially alleviated with a premade constants,

```
const Types = {
  'A': 'A',
  'B': 'B',
} as const;

// OKAY: type is B[] but it requires a premade constant
const okayListOfBs = arr.filter(narrow('type', Types.B));
```

it still doesn't prevent the issue of people forgetting `as const` with a literal value and getting confused why things don't work (as well as the fact that `as const` just looks ugly in the example two codeblocks above).

Is there a way to get TS to automatically infer a narrower type when provided with a string literal in `narrow` as shown above? Or at least a way to get a nice error message to show up?

[Playground link for all of the above code.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcCiIZQIYGMYBCOAdrgBYBiUEAtgKrECWExAPAFBxx0ByAkgHkeAGk5wAInwDKAYQBKfALJ8eAQR4AVOKBjBiAEwDOcANbBEEAGbd%20Q0VwJz1MgBLbMeozcE8A2pNkFZTVNAF1RAD44AF5vIXddA2M5YFxofVYA%20SUVdQ1hOEdnFyiAfjieOAAuOGJgADdgKABudnZQSFg4SwBXUhhmYlrsKGoAdw4uXh97CWls4LyEz2MzC2tpuzEinldlpIr-eaDcsMiACjF9RkNcKEYaRmJsXRqsk5D8sQAjEnIanauUQAShqly4jF0NBqmxE7GBMSikOANDgN3QmBw%20CI2FIlGo9CYLFYsIK7xynwKgJKcAA3mIoMAYD0oENzsiaKC0VC0cYMFg8IQ-vjaAxBiTbCI5oEKXkqU5djTohExBCob5rrd7o9nrpQjForFfrjyK0AL5tNpIFBwVQxOnW4A1ADkqmdzTg2BqhiwTwA5mbWo7CvbaY6XQR3XBvt7fcQA0HkKgpA8wAAbYBilj2u0AH0KrTSxB9ntGNRTNHTmaJxF8%20tidda7AA9M3CqpxDVg%20iK1Ws7XQuwiyXvth9AAZG4wASWAjGWIjKAAOksjDTuig52eowgY3OzsdzoKzsjwOBrVbcAA4gIBJ2EEneYU60OWCW-RAIBOpzO5-bFyua4blui67vuh7HpGnrGMOMBnk2sFwBoSbznSYius6LpurMJ6YXAuGiGa0FwLBTaXgIADSqgAJpdo%206IEHW0Y9PAkJwIyACOPSMIyxjYHAYCMjQY6oLBuIwK%20xbwBAJjYIgk4%20r%20qEAau65NCBO57geSZHkhKFLgQ8FAA)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to add extra restriction to `Branch` generic:

```js
export type ExtractBranchFromUnion<
  Union,
  Discriminant extends keyof Union,
  Branch extends Union[Discriminant],
  > = Union extends Record<Discriminant, Branch> ? Union : never;

export function narrow<
  Union,
  Discriminant extends keyof Union,
  Branch extends Union[Discriminant] & PropertyKey, // <------ change is here
  >(
    discriminate: Discriminant,
    Branch: Branch,
): (
    item: Union,
  ) => item is ExtractBranchFromUnion<Union, Discriminant, Branch> {
  return (item): item is ExtractBranchFromUnion<Union, Discriminant, Branch> =>
    item[discriminate] === Branch;
}



type A = { type: 'A'; a: string };
type B = { type: 'B'; b: string };

type SimpleUnion = A | B;
const arr: SimpleUnion[] = [];

const badListOfBs = arr.filter(narrow('type', 'B')); // B[]
const goodListOfBs = arr.filter(narrow('type', 'A')); // A[]
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/wX71VW)

I have added this: `Branch extends Union[Discriminant] & PropertyKey`.

I'd willing to bet that discriminator value should be `string | number | symbol`

As you might have noticed, I Capitalized all generic names because I found it hard to read. However this is the matter of preferences.

Comment: I'm confused as to why this works.  How is `PropertyKey` an additional constraint?  Without it, `Branch` resolves to `"A" | "B"`, but `"A"|"B"` satisfies `PropertyKey`, so why does it cause TS to narrow further?

Comment: This is because there are no constraints for `Union`. You can also use this constraint `Union extends Record<string, string>` like [here](https://tsplay.dev/WKVKom) and remove `& PropertyKey`. SUch constraints helps TypeScript to narrow the literal type.  See my [article](https://catchts.com/infer-arguments)

Comment: Amazing, thanks for the solution and explanations! Worked great.

For our use case, I made the tweak to have a `DiscriminantLiteral` type instead of `PropertyKey` (defined as `type DiscriminantLiteral = PropertyKey | boolean;`) because we occasionally may use `true`/`false` to distinguish union members.